# Terra function intersect() and crop() on large SpatVector returns Large list in R

Tags: r, gis, polygon, large-data, terra

I have what I think is a fairly simple workflow on ArcGIS that I am trying to automatise using `r/terra` to run different scenarios for the same flow. I am quite an advanced ArcMap user and fluent in R and data manipulation, but 100% new to Terra and this has left me stuck for days!

**Context:**
I have a large dataset of (multipart) polygons: ~2,000 species distributions in Australia including marine ones, with a spatial resolution of 1 or 10km each. There are 150,000 single polygons in total when fully disaggregated.

**Goal:**
I need to be able to calculate metrics related to species for each cell of a given grid. Metrics will include, but will not limited to, species number or area covered by each species. A `data.frame` containing all the information in the species distribution shapefile within each cell would be the ideal product.

**Issue:**
I tried `rasterize()` on aggregated data but it did not return the correct species count (I went through this https://github.com/rspatial/terra/issues/553 and was not able to fix, possibly because of all the tiny polygons involved).
I chose a less straightforward solution (but more practical for my needs) using `intersect()`. I end up with a `Large list` of thousands of elements (which I have no idea how to deal with) instead of a `SpatVector` (which I ultimately need for spatial data processing). It worked before but I am unable to pinpoint the issue. The same work flow works fine in ArcGIS on subset data.

```
library(terra)
library(dplyr)

# Load dummy data 
p <- vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
v <- p
cell_size <- 0.1 # in Decimal degrees

# Create grid cells
r <- rast(v, res=cell_size)
# Give a value (ID) to each cell and name this value
values(r) <- 1:ncell(r)
names(r) <- "CELLID"
# Transform raster grid to polygons grid
z <- as.polygons(r)
# Intersect with species
u <- intersect(z,v)
```

This is all I needed for subsequent data analysis (which will look like the line below, only including other metrics than simple species count).

```
# Create vector with unique species per cell
pa <- aggregate(u, by=c("CELLID","NAME_1"))
```

**Actual data:**
The data can be downloaded here: http://www.environment.gov.au/fed/catalog/search/resource/details.page?uuid=%7B337B05B6-254E-47AD-A701-C55D9A0435EA%7D

**Tried:**
I've tried many fixes on the base data, including subsetting the data spatially (`crop()` to a smaller area also returns a `Large list`), removing a bunch of those "issue" species, disaggregating, aggregating, fixing geometries, etc. I always end up with this large list either at the `crop()` step or the `intersect()` step.

Am I missing something obvious?

Sorry for the long post, I tried to include as much as I could.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The first thing to do in cases like this is to create a minimal, self-contained, reproducible example. That is, use data that ships with R (see the examples in terra) or that you create (e.g. a random sample); and clearly describe what you want to do (that is not very clear now, and you do rather suspect things like turning a raster into polygons). You should only include actual data to download if it is a clear need for it (e.g. a problem related to a specific file format).  Instead of `library(tidyverse)` list only the packages used. Can you please edit your question?

Comment: @RobertHijmans Thank you very much for your quick response. And even more so for making me quadruple check the obvious. The issue was simply a package conflict. Duh! The intersect() could not perform correctly because of the package "dplyr" I used to count the species. I will summarise my issue, the fix and mark as solved when I have a minute. Thanks again!

Answer (score 3):

Turns out I was, indeed, missing something obvious. The code snippet runs perfectly fine, except there was a conflict between `library(dplyr)` and `library(terra)` preventing terra functions such as `intersect()` and `crop()` from working properly. Duh! Thanks a lot Robert for pointing out the packages!

There are different ways to fix this but I will use the suggestions in [this link](https://towardsdatascience.com/attach-packages-mindfully-in-r-b9c8151b3fb4):

This is the new header of my script:

```
library(dplyr)
requireNamespace("terra")
```

Then I use `terra::` each time I will use a `terra` function. This option better suits the analyses that I will perform after that bit of code below.

```
# Load dummy data 
p <- terra::vect(system.file("ex/lux.shp", package="terra"))
v <- p
cell_size <- 0.1 # in Decimal degrees

# Create grid cells
r <- terra::rast(v, res=cell_size)
# Give a value (ID) to each cell and name this value
terra::values(r) <- 1:terra::ncell(r)
names(r) <- "CELLID"
# Transform raster grid to polygons grid
z <- terra::as.polygons(r)
# Intersect with species
u <- terra::intersect(z,v)
```